# NodeJS callback after multiple async-functions in for-loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, async-await, aggregation-framework

I get a document from a mongodb which contains an array with comments for that document. In the comment is the _id of the user which wrote the comment.

I now need to get the username based on the _id of the user, but I'm running into several problems.

I have the following code which, obviously, doesn't work, but I hope it can give you an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
//MORE CODE... (No need to show this here, just a promise, some try catch and so on)
let article = await Article.findOne({_id:articleid})   
    for(var i = 0; i<=article.comment.length-1; i++){
        User.findOne({_id:article.comment[i].user}).then((user)=>{
            article.comment[i].username = user.username
        })
    }
return resolve(article)
```

I looked up several documentations but wasn't able to find a working solution. I tried using Promise.all, played around with a lot of async, await, tried to add a counter into the for-loop and resolve the promise after the loop finished but nothing worked so far.

This is what the article looks like in my db

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18c1cbc47e5e29d42e4b0e"),
    "completed" : false,
    "completedAt" : null,
    "comment" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c18c95e328c8319ac07d817"),
            "comment" : "This is a comment",
            "rating" : [ ],
            "user" : ObjectId("5c18b76e73236d2168eda2b4")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c18fb578de5741f20a4e2bd"),
            "comment" : "Another comment",
            "rating" : [ ],
            "user" : ObjectId("5c18b76e73236d2168eda2b4")
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm rather new to nodejs and mongodb aswell so I hope you can help a newbie like me.

Thank you for your Help

Comment: You can either `await` in the loop (each findOne) or await a `Promise.all` over a `map` instead of a `loop. That said, the actual correct way to do this in Mongo would be to bulk-update and not find and update the documents one-by-one

Comment: This is what https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html is for, or you can attempt to use mongo's aggregation framework if you're feeling suicidal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are serveral approaches you can use here based on your convenience

**Using async await**

```
let article = await Article.findOne({ _id: articleid }).lean().exec()

await Promise.all(
  article.comment.map(async(obj) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ _id: obj.user })
    obj.username = user.username
  })
)

console.log(article)
```

**Using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation 3.6**

Since mongodb has its own powerfull [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation operator to join multiple collection and probably the better approach without any iteration

```
Article.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(articleid) }},
  { "$unwind": "$comment" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "let": { "userId": "$comment.user" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$$userId", "$_id"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "comment.user"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$comment.user" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "comment": { "$push": "$comment" },
    "completed": { "$first": "$completed" },
    "completedAt": { "$first": "$completedAt" }
  }}
])
```

**Using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) aggregation 3.4**

```
Article.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(articleid) }},
  { "$unwind": "$comment" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "users",
    "localField": "comment.user",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "comment.user"
  }}
  { "$unwind": "$comment.user" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "comment": { "$push": "$comment" },
    "completed": { "$first": "$completed" },
    "completedAt": { "$first": "$completedAt" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Both those approaches worked like a charm. Thank you very much for you quick and efficient help :)

Answer (score -2):

You can try like the following way

```
const d = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18c1cbc47e5e29d42e4b0e"),
    "completed" : false,
    "completedAt" : null,
    "comment" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c18c95e328c8319ac07d817"),
            "comment" : "This is a comment",
            "rating" : [ ],
            "user" : ObjectId("5c18b76e73236d2168eda2b4")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c18fb578de5741f20a4e2bd"),
            "comment" : "Another comment",
            "rating" : [ ],
            "user" : ObjectId("5c18b76e73236d2168eda2b4")
        }
    ]
}

d.comment.forEach( async (obj, index) => {
    await new Promise((res) => {
            obj.counter = index;
            res();
    })
});

console.log(d);
```

For reference please take a look on following link
[Asycn/Await using forEach](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404)

Comment: So in case of you have a list of 100 comments, it will take 100 seconds? You should avoid doing this.

Comment: ``` setTimeout(() => {
            obj.counter = index;
            res();
        }, 1000);``
the piece of code is for reference purpose not the actual one. 
I just gave an idea how can we do this. I didn't add the full-fledged code to copy paste. I think it's quite obvious to avoid timeout inside a loop :)

Comment: It makes sense. But it is still misleading.

Comment: Why to use `new Promise` as async function itself returns promise.

Comment: yes async default returns promises, but before updating the above answer used with setTimout fn which by default doesn't return promises as @crellee feels that above example with setTimeout make it confusing